# How to get all connected nodes(Incoming + Outgoing) from a given node using Gremlin

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I have a Knowledge Graph database and I need to query it using Gremlin to get all connected nodes(Incoming + Outgoing) for a given Node. Right now I am using an approach where I query it twice to get Incoming and Outgoing connections.
For outgoing connections, I am using -

```
"g.V().has('primaryName', 'NAME_OF_NODE').inE().outV().values('primaryName')"
```

For Incoming connections, I am using -

```
"g.V().has('primaryName', 'NAME_OF_NODE').outE().inV().values('primaryName')"
```

As of now I am running these as separate queries, is there any way to combine these two queries in a single query to save execution time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `bothE` instead.

```
g.V().has('primaryName','NAME_OF_NODE').
      bothE().
      otherV().
      values('primaryName')
```